# I was attempting this question of rotate array and getting TLE

Tags: java

I was attempting this question of rotate array and getting TLE

Here is my code

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to rotate an array by d elements in a counter-clockwise direction. 
    static void rotateArr(int arr[], int d, int n)
    {
        `// add your code here
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
             int left,j;
        left=arr[0];
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++){
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        }
        arr[n-1]=left;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If you mean "Time Limit Exceeded", then I don't see anything here that would cause it unless your inputs were very large.

Comment: Perhaps you should calculate where your elements will end up and just move them all once.

Comment: Yes, you are getting TLE because your algorithm is suboptimal - to rotate by k places, you are rotating by 1 place k times, in O(kn) time. You can rotate k places in O(n) time, independent of k, in several different ways. If your question is how to do that, then you can definitely find answers by searching, which you should do first before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your algorithm is **O(d*n)** or **O(n^2)** if d=n. You should do something more efficient than **O(n^2)**. I think **O(n)** is the best you can do. I know an **O(n)** solution for this problem,

First, reverse **all** the elements in the array. Then reverse the first **n-d** element and then reverse the last **d** element. The length of the array is **n**

For example,
rotate the array `A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` by **5** elements in a counter-clockwise direction.

first reverse all the elements,

```
A[] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

then reverse first n-d or (7-5) or 2 elements,

```
A[] = {6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

now reverse the last d or 5 elements,

```
A[] = {6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Upvote for not doing the coding for him. If you would now take a few seconds to nicely format your input, even better (for example by simply indenting the "code" by 4 spaces to get formatted as code)